# use `(boost::any a)` instead of `(const boost::any& a)` to prevent reference-to-reference

Tags: c++, boost, stl, boost-any

> First comes the definition of our new function object, contains_t. It
>   could have inherited from the helper class std::unary_function (part
>   of the C++ Standard Library, intended to facilitate the creation of
>   the correct typedefs) and have the argument and result types defined
>   automatically, but to make things clear, the required typedefs are
>   provided explicitly. **The argument type has changed from const
>   boost::any& to boost::any, to avoid a potential
>   reference-to-reference, which is illegal.** The implementation is just
>   as before, only here it is placed in the function call operator.

```
template <typename T> struct contains_t {
  typedef boost::any argument_type;
  typedef bool result_type;
  bool operator()(boost::any a) const {
    return typeid(T)==a.type();
  }
};
```

Why the following implementation has potential to receive reference-to-reference?

```
template <typename T> struct contains_t {
  typedef boost::any argument_type;
  typedef bool result_type;
  bool operator()(const boost::any& a) const {
    return typeid(T)==a.type();
  }
};
```

Thank you

Comment: What is that block quote from?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Beyond-Standard-Library-Introduction-Boost/dp/0321133544

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since boost::any can store anything, it can store references too. Therefore if you have a reference to a boost::any, you may accidentally end up with a reference to a reference internally.

i.e. boost::any can represent any type T. Let T be a reference of type U, i.e. T = U&. So taking a reference of the type T creates a reference to a reference of type U, which is not allowed in C++03 (C++11 will allow it though).